# Sonar Error - Make this member "protected"

Tags: java, sonarqube, protected

In the below class I am declaring myMap

```
public class AllMap {
    public static final Map<String, String> myMap= new HashMap<>();
    static {
        Map.put("yy", "AA");
        Map.put("xx", "BB");
    }
}
```

I need to access map in other class.

```
public class Test {
    FieldMap.Map;
}
```

Everything is working fine,but sonar is giving warning on 1st class:

> Make this member "protected".

on the line

```
public static final Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Should I ignore this warning or should I change it to protected?

Comment: Rule of thumb: Begin with private, change them one level up only when you have to. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, and how's your project structure, so I can't answer your question.

Comment: I would make myMap private and create a static accessor method.

Comment: agabrys's answer is what you need to do - to make your map unmodifiableMap  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sonar is giving you suggestion that your "member" which is:

`public final Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();`

should **not** be public.

**Why?**

Leaving this as `public` makes it available **from any other package** - so you are exposing the member to everybody. Below code is accessing the `member` directly:

```
AllMap allMap = new AllMap();
allMap.myMap.put("X", "Y");
```

In most cases `members` should be `private` and accessed by `getters` and `setters`, which could prevent with returning the same reference - so you can implement some logic before you `get` the reference or `set` it.

If you need to make it `static`, make `static` getters and setters.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to access the map in other classes, then you should protect it against modifications:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class AllMap {
    public static final Map<String, String> myMap;
    static {
        final Map<String, String> tmpMap = new HashMap<>();
        tmpMap.put("yy", "AA");
        tmpMap.put("xx", "BB");
        myMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tmpMap);
    }
}
```

You can still use it and SonarQube won't mark this as error (because the map is read-only).

Read more about [Collections#unmodifiableMap(Map)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap(java.util.Map)).

Answer (score 1):

Sonar lint issue because you are exposing references to mutable objects to client code.Here you are exposing a Map though it is final the final object allows clients to modify the contents of the object.

Never initialize such a field to a client-provided object reference or return the object reference from an accessor.

```
private static final SomeType [] THE_THINGS = { ... };
public static final List<SomeType> SOMETHINGS =
  Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(THE_THINGS));
```

[Reference link](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/607.html)

[Reference link2](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/582.html)